# Displaying different Fancybox based on validation - Too much recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, video.js

I have a list of images and when the image is clicked, I need to do an ajax URL call and validate some parameters.

If the validation is okay, I will have to show the fancybox else I should display another fancybox.

**My Issue:**
When I click on the image and if the validation is false the other fanybox displays as expected. But if the validation is true, Firebug throws an error saying "too much recursion".

**PS::** The expectations is that a video.js player will be shown if the validation is true.

**HTML Sample:**

```
<a id="videolink" href="#1" title="Test">
  <img class="vidimg" src="1.png" videoId="1" width="180" height="180" />
</a>

<div style="display:none">
      <video id="1" poster="1.png" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
        <source src="1362993728.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="1362993728.webm" type='video/webm'>    
        <source src="1362993728.ogv" type='video/ogg'>                 
    </video>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("a#videolink").click(function(){  
   $videoId = $(this).children("img.vidimg").attr("videoId"); 
   $isValid = "true" or "false" ;       // validation using .ajax() call

   if($isValid == 'true'){
      $(this).fancybox().click();
   }else{
      $("#myModal").fancybox().click()
   }                                             
});
```

The "too much recursion" is shown on the line by Firebug:

```
$videoId = $(this).children("img.vidimg").attr("videoId");
```

The other fanybox content to be displayed in case of "false":

```
 <div style="display:none">
    <div id="myModal"> Invalid Item</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please let me know if any other information is needed on this.

Answer (score 0):

The below changes helped me to have this work as expected.. (there are still some issues in having the fancybox video play).

**HTML Sample:**

```
<div style="display:none">
  <div id="1">
      <video poster="1.png" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
        <source src="1362993728.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
        <source src="1362993728.webm" type='video/webm'>    
        <source src="1362993728.ogv" type='video/ogg'>                 
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("img.vidimg").click(function(){  
   $videoId = $(this).attr("videoId"); 
   $isValid = "true" or "false" ;       // validation using .ajax() call

   if($isValid == 'true'){
      $('#' + $videoId ).fancybox().click();
   }else{
      $("#myModal").fancybox().click()
   }                                             
});
```

Any comments on this related to performance or bad code practice with reference to this code?

I will create a new question here for the video player issue. After this change, the video does not play. :(